# How to delete rows in a CSV file based on blank columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file that is in this format, but has thousands of rows so I can summarize it like this

```
id,name,score1,score2,score3
1,,3.0,4.5,2.0
2,,,,
3,,4.5,3.2,4.1
```

I have tried to use .dropna() but that is not working.

My desired output is

```
id,name,score1,score2,score3
1,,3.0,4.5,2.0
3,,4.5,3.2,4.1
```

All I would really need is to check if score1 is empty because if score1 is empty then the rest of the scores are empty as well.

I have also tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

df.drop(df.index[(df["score1] == '')], axis=0,inplace=True)

df.to_csv('new.csv')
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `df.dropna(subset=['score1'])` or `df[df['score1'].ne("")]`

Comment: simple `dropna` is working for me. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @krxat I'm not getting any errors, it just returns me the same dataset with all the blanks, what's the exact code you're running?

Comment: Check [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QzjOIt5V-yKKlONE42iH7PtZpYTcKA0b?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have updated my post to be more clear why mine was failing, every field has 1 blank in it somewhere so if I just do dropna() it deletes every row, but I only want to delete the rows where the score1 is blank

Comment: @krxat see my new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your edits, I realized that `dropna` doesn't work for you because you have a `None` value in all of your rows. To filter for `nan` values in a specific column, I would recommend using the `apply` function like in the following code. (Btw the `StackOverflow.csv` is just a file where I copied and pasted your data from the question)

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.read_csv("StackOverflow.csv", index_col="id")

#Function that takes a number and returns if its nan or not
def not_nan(number):
    return not math.isnan(number)

#Filtering the dataframe with the function
df = df[df["score1"].apply(not_nan)]
```

What this does is iterate through the `score1` row and check if a value is `NaN` or not. If it is, then it returns False. We then use the list of `True` and `False` values to filter out the values from the dataframe.

Comment: that worked great, exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: This works but pandas have an inbuilt functionality for this same thing. Just give the column name as `subset` for `dropna`. It would look something like this `df.dropna(subset=['score1'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3.0,4.5,2.0],[2],[3,4.5,3.2,4.1]], columns=["id","score1","score2","score3"])

aux1 = df.dropna()
aux2 = df.dropna(axis='columns')
aux3 = df.dropna(axis='rows')

print('=== original ===')
print(df)
print()
print('=== mode 1 ===')
print(aux1)
print()
print('=== mode 2 ===')
print(aux2)
print()
print('=== mode 3 ===')
print(aux3)
print()
print('=== mode 4 ===')
print('drop original')
df.dropna(axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```